# jquery jqgrid no results displayed depending on parameters in json object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jqgrid

I have set up a jqgrid and it loads the data via php. No results are displayed

The grid is set up with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#list_records").jqGrid({
url: "grid.php",
datatype: "json",
mtype: "GET",
colNames: ["ID", "Encuesta", "Fecha", "Quien","Opciones"],
colModel: [
{ name: "id_consulta"},
{ name: "texto"},
{ name: "fecha"},
{ name: "quien"},
{name:'act',index:'act', width:130,sortable:false,formatter:myFormatter, search:false}
],
pager: "#perpage",
rowNum: 8,
rowList: [10,20],
sortname: "id_consulta",
sortorder: "asc",
height: 'auto',
viewrecords: true,
gridview: true,
caption: ""
});

$('#list_records').jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch : "bw"});

});


function myFormatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
    var idconsulta = rowObject[0];
    return "</a><input type=button value='Enviar' onclick=\"loadingForm(" + idconsulta + ");\" />";
}
```

And the corrsponding json output from the php files is

```
{"page":1,"total":2,"records":"18","rows":[{"id":"18","cell":["18","Camila quieres participar? ","2015-03-02","dwk"]},{"id":"17","cell":["17","Halo concepci\u00f3n wie gehts ","2015-03-02","idkl"]},{"id":"16","cell":["16","\u00bfAlguien quiere participar?","2015-03-02","dwk"]},{"id":"15","cell":["15","\u00bfEs \u00fatil una aplicaci\u00f3n para realizar encuestas instant\u00e1neas? ","2015-03-02","idkl"]},{"id":"14","cell":["14","Camila quieres participar? ","2015-03-02","idkl"]},{"id":"13","cell":["13","Halo concepci\u00f3n wie gehts ","2015-03-02","idkl"]},{"id":"12","cell":["12","\u00bfAlguien quiere participar?","2015-03-02","dwk"]},{"id":"11","cell":["11","\u00bfEs \u00fatil una aplicaci\u00f3n para realizar encuestas instant\u00e1neas? ","2015-03-02","idkl"]},{"id":"10","cell":["10","Halo concepci\u00f3n wie gehts ","2015-03-02","dwk"]},{"id":"9","cell":["9","\u00bfAlguien quiere participar?","2015-03-02","idkl"]}]}
```

if I remove

```
$responce->page = $page;
$responce->total = $total_pages;
$responce->records = $count;
```

I get results displayed but can not use pagination

Comment: Is "perpage" the same id of div you want to used for pagination ?

Comment: @AlankarMore Hello, yes i use two divs list_records for the grid and perpage for the pager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution that works for me so to set up a jqgrid via php mysql with filtering via toolbar and paging i used the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('#rowed2').jqGrid({
    url:'server.php',
    datatype: 'json',
     colNames:['ID','ENCUESTA', 'FECHA', 'QUIEN','ACTIONS'], 
       colModel:[ 
        { name: 'id_consulta',width:30,search:false,sortable:false},
        { name: 'texto', width:250},
        { name: 'fecha', width:65},
        { name: 'quien', width:100},
        {name:'act',index:'act', width:100,sortable:false,formatter:myFormatter, search:false}     
       ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#prowed2',
    sortname: 'ID',
        viewrecords: true,
    height: '400',
    width: '600',
        sortorder: 'asc'
});

$('#rowed2').jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch : "bw"});

});


function myFormatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
    var idconsulta = rowObject[0];
    return "</a><input type=button value='Ver Resultado' onclick=\"loadingForm(" + idconsulta + ");\" />";
}
```

the php file used is the following

```
<?php

 error_reporting(0);
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
 require_once 'cliente/config.php';

$db = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$db);

 $page = $_GET['page']; // get the requested page
 $limit = $_GET['rows']; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid
 $sidx = $_GET['sidx']; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort
 $sord = $_GET['sord']; // get the direction
 if(!$sidx) $sidx =1; // connect to the database


$filterResultsJSON = json_decode($_GET['filters']);
$counter = 0;
$sql='';

if($filterResultsJSON != "") {

$filterArray = get_object_vars($filterResultsJSON);

while($counter < count($filterArray['rules']))
{
$filterRules = get_object_vars($filterArray['rules'][$counter]);

if($counter == 0){
$sql .= ' WHERE ' . $filterRules['field'] . ' LIKE "%' . $filterRules['data'] . '%"';
}
else {
$sql .= ' AND ' . $filterRules['field'] . ' LIKE "%' . $filterRules['data'] . '%"';
}
$counter++;
}

}

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM consulta $sql");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
 $count = $row['count'];

 if( $count >0 ) { 
 $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
 } else { 
 $total_pages = 0; 
 }

 if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
 if ($limit<0) $limit = 0; 
 $start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)
 if ($start<0) $start = 0;

 $SQL2 = "SELECT * from consulta $sql ORDER BY id_consulta desc LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
 $result = mysql_query( $SQL2 ) or die("Couldn?t execute query.".mysql_error());

 $responce->page = $page;
 $responce->total = $total_pages;
 $responce->records = $count;

 $i=0;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
 $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row[id_consulta];
 $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row['id_consulta'],utf8_encode($row['texto']),$row[fecha],$row[quien],""); $i++;
 } 
 echo json_encode($responce);

?>
```